# Show that 13 divides $2^{70}+3^{70}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that $13$ divides $2^{70} + 3^{70}$.

My main problem here is trying to figure out how to separate the two elements in the sum, and then use Fermat's little theorem. So how can I separate the two?

Thanks!

Comment: Argh, typo! Should be 3^70. Same exponent, different base. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't rely on the subject for content; the body should be self-contained.

Comment: @Arturo Alright. :) Thanks for editing it for me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compute $2^{70}$ and $3^{70}$ modulo $13$ *separately* (e.g., using Fermat's Little Theorem). If $2^{70}\equiv a\pmod{13}$ and $3^{70}\equiv b\pmod{13}$, then what is $2^{70}+3^{70}$ congruent to modulo 13?

Comment: Aah. I knew I could add them up easily but was coming from the wrong direction, trying to do it backwards. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 23):

Okay, I'm on a little different wavelength so I'll turn my comment into an answer.. if $n$ is odd the polynomial $x + y$ divides $x^n + y^n$. So letting $x = 2^2, y = 3^2,$ and $n = 35$ you get that $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$ divides $2^{70} + 3^{70}$.

Comment: now there's a creative solution! nice to see someone who doesn't just immediately do brute force mods.

Comment: @Eug But its simplest proof is by mod, viz. mod $\rm\ A+B\::\ \ A\:\equiv\: -B\ \Rightarrow\ A^{2\:N\:+\:1}\equiv\: -B^{2\:N\:+\:1}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$

Answer (score 6):

$2^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ and $3^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Hence, $2^{72} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ and $3^{72} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$

$2^{72} \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow 2^{72} \equiv 40 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow 2^{70} \equiv 10 \pmod{13}$

$3^{72} \equiv 1 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow 3^{72} \equiv 27 \pmod{13} \Rightarrow 3^{70} \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$

Hence, you get the result.

Comment: Thanks! Walking through it like that was very helpful to figure out just what kinds of operations are allowed with congruences. Thanks!

Comment: @Christoph: You are allowed to cancel since gcd(2,13) = 1 = gcd(3,13)

Comment: @Sivaram: Do you use `\bmod` on purpose rather than `\pmod`? Not criticising, just wondering; I know a lot of LaTeX users of long standing that are suprised to find out that `\pmod` exists...

Comment: Oooh yeah! Division works because inversion works, which only works for mod p, p is prime. Correct?

Comment: @Arturo: Nice, I didn't know about \pmod. Thanks!

Comment: @Arturo: I didn't know that \pmod exists. Have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT** $\rm\: $ Little Fermat shows $\rm\ mod\ 13:\ \ 2^{70} + 3^{70}\ \equiv\ 2^{-2} + 3^{-2}\ \equiv\ 1/4+1/9\ \equiv 13/36\ \equiv\ 0$

**NOTE** $\ $ For a slight generalization [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37556/can-this-number-theory-mcq-be-solved-in-4-minutes/37654#37654)

Answer (score 3):

The "quick" way to do this is as follows:

$2^{6}=64=-1$(mod 13), $3^{3}=1$ (mod 13)

Hence you have $2^{70}=(2^{6})^{11}*2^{4}=(-1)*(3)=-3$ (mod 13)

And $3^{70}=(3^{3})^{13}*3=3$ (mod 13)

Therefore the result is $-3+3=0$ (mod 13).

Fermat's little theorem implies $a^{p-1}\cong 1$ (mod p), but this may be more slick, I am not sure. Mind that Fermat's little theorem is not optimal in many cases.

The "ultra quick" way may be $2^{70}+3^{70}=3^{70}*(1+(2/3)^{70})$. Now notice $2/3=2*9=5$. And $5^2=-1$, hence $(1+(5^{2})^{25})=1+-1=0$. Therefore $2^{70}+3^{70}=0$.

Comment: Well, I'd say, "the ultraquick" way is the following: $ \mod 13:2^{70}+3^{70} ==4^{35}+9^{35}  == (4^1+9^1)x ==0 $

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So by FlT, you know that $2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $3^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. So 
$$
2^{70}+3^{70}\equiv (2^{12})^5\cdot 2^{10}+(3^{12})^5\cdot 3^{10}\equiv 2^{10}+3^{10}\pmod{13}.
$$
However, again by FlT, 
$$
2^{12}\equiv 2^{10}\cdot 2^{2}\equiv 1\pmod{13}\implies 2^{10}\equiv 2^{-2}\pmod{13}.
$$
That is to say, $2^{10}$ is congruent to the multiplicative inverse of $4$ modulo $13$. You can do the same for $3^{10}$, except you will need to find the multiplicative inverse to $9$ modulo $13$. You'll see that the sum of these inverses is $0$ modulo $13$, to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $a_n=2^n+3^n \bmod 13$ is periodic of period $12$
$$
2,5,0,9,6,2,0,1,5,6,0,3,\color{red}{2,5,0,9,6,2,0,1,5,6,0,3},\dots
$$
Therefore, $a_{n} = 0$ iff $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, which holds for $n=70$.