# How can I disprove that $13\mid 2^{70}+5^{70}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I started with *Fermat's Little Theorem* taking $2^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$ and raising it to power $5$, we got $2^{60}\equiv1\pmod{13}$, then multiplied the congruence $2^{10}\equiv(-3)\pmod{13}$.

I did the same with $5$ and I get $2^{70}+5^{70}\equiv(-4)\pmod{13}$.

Is another method to find it

Comment: I agree with you.  $2^{70}+5^{70}\equiv 9 \pmod {13}$.

Comment: Everything you said is correct. What you're trying to prove is not true. $13$ does not divide $2^{70} + 5^{70}$.

Comment: Why did you roll back to a wrong edition of your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that 13 divides $2^{70}+3^{70}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/show-that-13-divides-270370)

Comment: A correct formulation is already on the site.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing quite well: $2^{12}\equiv1\pmod{13}$, so
$$
2^{70}=(2^{12})^5\cdot2^{10}\equiv2^{10}\pmod{13}
$$
Now note that $2\cdot7\equiv1\pmod{13}$, so $2^{10}\equiv2^{12}\cdot7^{2}\equiv7^2\pmod{13}$ and finally
$$
2^{70}\equiv49\equiv10\pmod{13}
$$
With similar computations, noting that $5\cdot8\equiv1\pmod{13}$ we have
$$
5^{70}\equiv(5^{12})^6\cdot8^2\equiv64\equiv12\pmod{13}
$$
This shows
$$
2^{70}+5^{70}\equiv10+12\equiv9\not\equiv0\pmod{13}
$$